# Ajax response seems to be getting lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the ddslick jquery dropdown plugin in conjunction with my Rails app.

In view1, I have

```
$('#challenges_dropdown').ddslick({
  <snipped>
  onSelected: function (data) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/load_data",
      type: "GET",
      data: {"id": data.selectedData.value}
    });
  }
});
```

I.e., I make a call to my controller to load_data. The controller receives this correctly and then at the end, makes a call to render a separate view

```
render "data.js"
```

This is a .js view that executes a script which updates some elements of my original view. For some reason, this script snippet is just not running.

I'm very confused. When I use a regular link with data-remote="true", then the whole process works perfectly. However, when I make an AJAX call, it fails.

Comment: I see you making an ajax call, but you never did anything with it's response.

Comment: Yes, usually you'd have something wired to the success of the ajax call to handle the response.  One thing to narrow down the problem is to hit F12 in the browser and switch to network tab, activate the click and then look at for the post and drill into the response.  You can look and see if the response has an error, and also the console/javascript errors will indicate if there is some javascript error occurring in your code.  Most browsers have pretty good debugging tools like this and most are under F12.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions! I've edited my problem - you'll see that basically, the render happens on a .js file. How do I ensure that basically the response for my ajax call should ... execute?

Comment: got it! see my solution below. Thanks a lot for the responses, folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I needed to specify a dataType for the AJAX call so that the response from the AJAX call would be seen as a script and thus executed:

```
$('#challenges_dropdown').ddslick({
  <snipped>
  onSelected: function (data) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/load_data",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "script",
      data: {"id": data.selectedData.value}
    });
  }
});
```